# How do I serve image files (jpg) present in directories of their own classes to a Tensorflow Estimator for training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Directory structure:

```
Data
-Cats
--<images>.jpg
-Dogs
--<images>.jpg
```

I'm training a (n-ary) classification model. I want to create an input_fn for serving these images for training.

image dimensions are (200, 200, 3). I have a (keras) generator for them, if they can be used somehow.

I've been looking for a while but haven't found an easy way to do this. I thought this should be a standard use-case? e.g. Keras provides flow_from_directory to serve keras models. I need to use a tf.estimator for AWS Sagemaker so I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

By using the tf dataset Module you can feed your data directly into your estimator.  You basically have 3 ways to integrate this into your api: 
1. convert your images into tfrecords and use [tfrecorddataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset)
2 use the [tf dataset from generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) function to use generators 
3 try introducing these decoder [functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image)  into your inputpipeline